# Fifth Browser - how do I get the configure script to recognise a dependency?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, browser

I am trying to install Fifth Browser ([website](http://fifth-browser.sourceforge.net/)) ([github link](https://github.com/clbr/fifth)) on Xubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

I was able to get all of the dependencies via the official distro repositories, using Synaptic for installation. One of them [as listed on fifth's homepage](http://fifth-browser.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) is called liburlmatch ([github link](http://github.com/clbr/urlmatch)). It appears to be a simple library that lets you block URLs while using wildcards.

I have installed urlmatch via:
/git clone  https://github.com/clbr/urlmatch.git and then
/sudo checkinstall in a separate folder. This seemed to work flawlessly.

When I do ./configure in the fifth folder the last few lines look like this:

```
checking for fltk-config13... no
checking for fltk-config... fltk-config
checking for url_init in -lurlmatch... no
configure: error: liburlmatch not found
```

You can find the part of the configure file pertaining to urlmatch in the following pastebin to your convenience: [codeblock from configure for liburlmatch](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24948524/).

What am I doing wrong? 
Why doesn't the configure script recognise the urlmatcher library?
Please consider in your answer that this is one of my first attempts to compile a programme like this, thanks.

Comment: *"seemed to work flawlessly"* - did you check for a `liburlmatch.*` in `/usr/lib`?

Comment: there is a liburlmatch.a (AR archive), but not 'shared library' like the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is actually to do with how the configure script for fifth-5.0 constructs and runs the conftest for the urlmatch library.

First, the error

```
checking for url_init in -lurlmatch... no
configure: error: liburlmatch not found
```

turns out to be somewhat misleading: if we look at the `config.log` we see that the conftest is actually failing to build because of an undefined reference to the `uncompress` function:

```
configure:5511: checking for url_init in -lurlmatch
configure:5546: g++ -o conftest -g -O2 -pthread  -isystem /usr/include/cairo -isystem /usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem /usr/include/pixman-1 -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/libpng12 -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/cairo -isystem /usr/include/glib-2.0 -isystem /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -isystem /usr/include/pixman-1 -isystem /usr/include/freetype2 -isystem /usr/include/libpng12 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT   -lz conftest.cpp -lurlmatch    -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lfltk_images -lfltk -lX11 >&5
//usr/local/lib/liburlmatch.a(opti_init.o): In function `initbin':
opti_init.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `uncompress'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:5552: $? = 1
```

That's because `uncompress` is in `libz` - which is being linked *before* `liburlmatch`:

```
. . .   -lz conftest.cpp -lurlmatch -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lfltk_images -lfltk -lX11 >&5
```

failing to respect the necessary link order<sup>1</sup> for the two libraries. We can trace that back further to the `configure.ac` file from which the `configure` script would have been generated:

```
# Checks for libraries.
OLD_LDFLAGS=[$LDFLAGS]
LDFLAGS=["$LDFLAGS -lz"]
AC_CHECK_LIB([urlmatch], [url_init], [], AC_MSG_ERROR([liburlmatch not found]))
LDFLAGS=[$OLD_LDFLAGS]
```

i.e. rather than being added to the list of `LIBS`, `-lz` is added to the `LDFLAGS` (which is more typically used to specify additional library *paths* ahead of the `LIBS`).

A quick'n'dirty workaround is to call `./configure` with an explicit `LIBS` argument:

```
./configure "LIBS=-lz"
```

This causes an extra `-lz` to be placed on the `g++` command line *after* the `urlmatch` library (at the head of the other `LIBS`):

```
. . . -lz conftest.cpp -lurlmatch -lz -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lfltk_images -lfltk -lX11 >&5
```

A more permanent solution might be to modify the `configure.ac` file to add `-lz` to `LIBS` instead of `LDFLAGS`, and then re-generate `configure` using `autoconf` (or `autoreconf` if necessary).

---

Refs.:

1. [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894098/4440445)

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this in detail. I'm frightfully sorry, it seems this issue has been fixed on github after the latest tarball release v0.5. Still I am learning from your analysis. Thanks again!